# How to migrate GCS bucket from one project to another in different account

Tags: google-cloud-storage

How to transfer GCS bucket from one account to another account without downloading data

Is Transfer Service for Cloud Data Chargable?

Answer (score 1):

You don't transfert GCS bucket from an account to another one. The GCS bucket belong to a project.

You can grant new user on the project, on only on the bucket to allow them access. You can also create another bucket, in another project, with another name (project id and bucket name are global resources, 2 can't have the same name all around the world) and use Transfer service to duplicate the data. The service is free of charge if the data stay in the same region (if not, egress cost will be applied)